# Network Interface problems with Elkhart Lake platform

Tags: networking, nic

I am using the following board from congatech:
https://www.congatec.com/de/produkte/pico-itx/conga-pa7/
which is a pico itx based elkhart lake board.

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed.

The network interface is an Intel EC1000R MAC-Chip integrated in the Intel-SOC

For the dual network interfaces to work, I had to change the grub config file:
quiet splash i915.force_probe=* swiotlb=65536 module_blacklist=dp83867

I now can use both interfaces, but they seem to be very slow. Also I cannot change the mtu to a value higher than 1500.

Anybody any ideas?

Comment: What does very slow mean?

Comment: The compatibility list for this hardware is useless it just says Ubuntu no version info.

Comment: The Elkhart Lake platform is newer than Ubuntu 20.04. Don't expect an older OS to provide best experience on newer hardware. Test a newer release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried Ubuntu 22.04 yet on this? 20.04 is old enough it might not have support fully for this board, but 22.04 is newer and might have more support.

Comment: Tried the official Ubuntu 22.04 Release for elkhart lake. Same Problem, network interfaces are detected, but do not connect. Would need the blacklisting I mentioned.
Slow means that for example it cannot do 4k Videos on Youtube, lags or hangs.

Comment: Found out that only the second ethernet port is slow, first works as expected with the blacklisting. Will try to contact hardware vendor, maybe it is a hardware problem. MTU however can only be set to max of 4092, which is also strange.